# return json object fron function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to return a json object from a function and use it as the below code, but it's not working. what wrong with it?

```
var x = [ "EditFileName" , "dosometing" ];
c_loadAjax.apply(this,x).done(function(json){
    alert(json.error);
});
function c_loadAjax( post , option ){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/includes/Ajax.php",
        data:{post:post,option:option},
        error:function(result){
            return '{"error":"Error"}';
        },
        success:function(result){
            return jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you have to return the deferred object itself to use it with `.done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the return keyword

```
var x = [ "EditFileName" , "dosometing" ];
c_loadAjax.apply(this,x).done(function(json){
    alert(json.error);
});
function c_loadAjax( post , option ){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/includes/Ajax.php",
        data:{post:post,option:option},
        error:function(result){
            return '{"error":"Error"}';
        },
        success:function(result){
            return jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it's actually returning data as json and works fine. but is it really okey to use it like this?

Comment: no, prefer ask for datatype:'json' in your request and give callbacks (success and fail functions) to your c_loadAjax as parameters