# Get JSON's content from Partial View (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have a Controller to return JSON

```
    public ActionResult Project()
    {
        var q = from p in db.projects
                select new { p.name_project, p.contract_value };

        return Json(q.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And I created a Partial View name "Project.cshtml" to get JSON and print result

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('/Chart/Project', function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            items.push('<li>' + key + ': ' + val.Title + ' (' + val.Count + ')</li>');
        });

        $('<ul />', {
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    })
</script>
```

I call Partial View by HTMLHepler Html.Partial("Project") in Index.cshtml but it returned javascript code, I want to get the content after that code is done!

Comment: Write $.getJSON function in $(document).ready(function(){ $.getJSON... });

Comment: If you always return JSON, you might want to replace the ActionResult with a JsonResult in your actions signature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the json content in your getJson method as follows:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

then use this result in your `$.each` function.

[Return Json content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134321/return-json-object-fron-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your $.getJson() call isn't getting executed when the partial view is rendered. You need to wrap it in a $.ready() function (as below) or in a javascript self executing function

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $.getJSON('/Chart/Project', function (data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
          items.push('<li>' + key + ': ' + val.Title + ' (' + val.Count + ')</li>');
      });

      $('<ul />', {
          html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('body');
    })
  });
</script>
```